# Pass input value to id in MVC from view

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I pass the value of an input box from a view, to the URL as the ID rather than a GET parameter?

My home controller returns an additional view if the query string is empty.

> localhost:1111/home/job/1

would return a list of results from a table based on the id, whereas:

> localhost:1111/home/job

will return the "Empty" view.

The Empty view contains a very simple form that is functional, and returns table results, however, I need the URL to be in the correct format {controller}/{action}/{id} where the id is from the input. Whereas I am currently getting {controller}/{action}/?jobno=1

Empty View:

```
<form action='home/job/' method="post">
    <input type="text" name="jobno"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Try replacing the `action='home/job/'` to `action='/home/job'`

Comment: I've tried that, the form and resulting view do work, I just need the input value to be passed into the url. For example if the input value was 999, I need the URL to read "home/job/999" instead of just "home/job" or "home/job?jobno=999"

Comment: are you comfortable with `jQuery`, that will append the querystring

Comment: I've never really used jQuery before no

Comment: ok, so i'll post you javascript that does this job. The form that you have posted is the rendered HTML markup ? or else you have just hand coded as form ?

Comment: Ok brilliant, it's just a hand coded form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try like this:

```
<form id="form1"  action='/home/job/' method="post"> 
    <input id="jobno" type="text" name="jobno"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="AddingQS();">/>
</form>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    function AddingQS(){
        var formaction=document.getElementById('form1');
        formaction.action+=document.getElementById('jobno').value;      
    }
  </script>
```

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G4Qev/)

Comment: It's still giving the same result: "/home/job/" without the input value attached to the end. I presume it's something to do with MVC 4 and the way it handles the routing

Comment: Still not working, I don't understand why it's not working for me if it's working for you! haha

Comment: I've tried it @user2071225, That worked perfect for me. have you kept id of form as `form1`